# Trigger Google Cloud Function using JWT

Tags: google-cloud-functions, jwt, service-accounts

I am trying to trigger a Google cloud function using an HTTP request and a service account.
I followed these steps :

1. Create a service account
2. Download JSON key file
3. Create a Google Cloud function that requires authentication (this is a test function that just returns "Hello world !"
4. In the Cloud function permissions I added my service account with the role Cloud Functions Invoker

If I generate an identity token with this service account (gcloud auth print-identity-token) and use it to trigger my Cloud function (with `Authorization: Bearer $ID_TOKEN` in headers) it works as expected.
But now I want to be able to do it in production. So what I did is generate a JWT, use it to get an access token and use this access token just like I did with the identity token but I get 401 Unauthorized response.

Here is my code (Python)

```
import jwt
import time
import requests

# These elements are found in the service account JSON file (step 2)
PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON = "123ab4cdefghi56jk789123456789f123456m7n"
PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "ACCOUNT_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

# Create JWT
iat = int(time.time())
exp = iat + 3600

payload = {
    'iss': SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    'sub': SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    'aud': "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    'target_audience ': 'https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME',
    'iat': iat,
    'exp': exp,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
}
additional_headers = {'kid': PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON}

signed_jwt = jwt.encode(
    payload,
    PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON,
    headers=additional_headers,
    algorithm='RS256'
)

# Use JWT to get access token
resp = requests.post(
    f"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    f"?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={signed_jwt}",
    headers={
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {signed_jwt}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
)

access_token = resp.json()["access_token"]

# Trigger Cloud Function using this access token
resp_cf = requests.post(
    "https://europe-west1-cuure-265415.cloudfunctions.net/Test_service_account",
    headers={
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
)

print(resp_cf.content)
```

The result is the following

```
b'\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/CLOUD FUNCTION NAME</code>.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n'
```

I don't want to use Python libraries to authenticate my request with the service account because my aim is to be able to reproduce this in Bubble.io, a no code development platform.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the identity token instead ;)

Comment: @Dylan Nina Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57125081/15774176) :

> There are three types of OAuth tokens. Refresh Token, Access Token,
> Identity Token. You are trying to use an OAuth Access Token instead of
> an OAuth Identity Token. For Authorization, Google Cloud Functions
> uses an OAuth Identity Token in the authorization: bearer HTTP header.

You can also refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#exchanging_a_self-signed_jwt_for_a_google-signed_id_token) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62310571/15774176) where exchanging a self-signed JWT for a Google-signed ID token is well explained.

> You can manage access to an HTTP Cloud Function using IAM roles. You
> will want to assign the roles/cloud functions.invoker role to a
> service account, and have the caller provide the oauth credentials to
> the function in the Authorization header.

Comment: I already followed the steps of this documentation.
First I create a JWT and then I make a request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to include the id_token in my JWT. Finally, I use the JWT with the id_token included to call my cloud function (Bearer XXX in the headers)

Comment: is this issue resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is CLoud functions 2nd gen is not working with this type of endpoint 'https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME'. GCP generates a URL for the function